# OpenGL and xml Android

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I want to use xml to set position and other properties, use also other elements.

So, my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center">

<TextView
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <android.opengl.GLSurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/mglid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="Small Button"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My main class:

```
package com.mycompany.opengl2;

import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.ConfigurationInfo;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

/** Hold a reference to our GLSurfaceView */
public GLSurfaceView mGLSurfaceView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mGLSurfaceView = new GLSurfaceView(this);

    // Check if the system supports OpenGL ES 2.0.
    final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)            
        getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final ConfigurationInfo configurationInfo = activityManager.getDeviceConfigurationInfo();
    final boolean supportsEs2 = configurationInfo.reqGlEsVersion >= 0x20000;

    if (supportsEs2)
    {
        // Request an OpenGL ES 2.0 compatible context.
        mGLSurfaceView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);

        // Set the renderer to our demo renderer, defined below.
        mGLSurfaceView.setRenderer(new LessonOneRenderer());
    }
    else
    {
        // This is where you could create an OpenGL ES 1.x compatible
        // renderer if you wanted to support both ES 1 and ES 2.
        return;
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mGLSurfaceView = (GLSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.mglid);
}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    // The activity must call the GL surface view's onResume() on activity onResume().
    super.onResume();
    mGLSurfaceView.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    // The activity must call the GL surface view's onPause() on activity onPause().
    super.onPause();
    mGLSurfaceView.onPause();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.LessonOneRenderer.menu, menu);
    return true;
}
  }
```

In other class LessonOneRenderer I have render with function which draw three triangles.

Whole code here(Russian translation, but code is primary source)
http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/layout/framelayout.php

Finally, how can I use xml to setup GLSurfaceView view on screen with other elements. 
Thanks

Comment: You're not saying what problem you have with your code. One issue is certainly that you're using `mGLSurfaceView` before its value is assigned. It's generally much cleaner and easier if you derive your own class from `GLSurfaceView`, and do the setup of the view in its constructor.

Comment: I have just one problem.  Code works when I run only GLSurfaceView by the SetContentView(mGLSurfaceView). But if I try to write it in xml and run SetContentView(R.id.main) I got always "Application was stop" after run because can't reference to android.opengl.GLSurfaceView or any other same error like this.

Comment: Sorry, don't "SetContentView(R.id. main)" but "SetContentView(R.layout.main)"